# Making my main menu a hamburger menu on all platforms

Tags: menus, themes, css

I am working on a wordpress site, using the Zephyr material design theme. My main menu is getting longer, and it overflows out of the page, making it look awkward and badly designed. On mobile, this is not an issue as the menu is a hamburger menu and therefore can be scrolled through easily no matter the length. How can I turn this menu into a hamburger on PC as well?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. I simply made all my pages into dropdown options for the homepage link so that there's only one item on the main menu, and hovering gives you the rest in a dropdown format.